# Why won't LightDM start properly after installing OSSEC?

Tags: greeter, luna

After installing OSSEC in Luna, LightDM can not find `/usr/share/xgreeters/default.desktop` and just stops. Uninstalling OSSEC does not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link default.desktop to pantheon-greeter.desktop:

```
cd /usr/share/xgreeters  
sudo ln -s pantheon-greeter.desktop default.desktop
```

Comment: This would require `sudo` privileges.

Comment: Why yes it would. Corrected. Thank you. And yes, it did work for me.

Comment: @user2628103 if this solution worked for you, please mark this answer as having solved your question

Comment: I tried to mark it answered yesterday, but stackexchange makes you wait 2 days to mark your own answer as the solution -- a necessary speed hump to prevent abuse, I assume.